# Custom cell in Universal application + swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, universal

I have a universal application in swift. In one table view display data from a custom cell.

Now my question is do I need to create seperate  custom cells
or using one custom cell I can use it iPhone and iPad. 
If yes, how to use a single custom cell for both of them

Comment: Are you using storyboards or wring your UI programatically ?

Comment: I am using storyboard

Comment: I am new to swift and please let me know how to proceed in this case

Comment: What is your suggestion to use in this case?

Comment: custom table view cells in swift

Comment: My question is do I need to create seperate custom cells or using one custom cell I can use it iPhone and iPad. If yes, how to use a single custom cell for both of them